# Horizontal alignment of columns

Tags: tables, alignment, horizontal

How can I leave the final 2 columns, evenly spaced horizontally?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow,amsmath}
\providecommand\legend[1]{#1} % ??
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h] 
\caption{Análise de Sensibilidade dos parâmetros $\overline{N u}_{L_{p}}$ 
  e $R a_{L_{P}}$, em função das respectivas incertezas de medição 
  de influência.} 
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}%
   Variação Percentual da\\ 
   Incerteza de Medição
   \end{tabular}} & 
\multicolumn{5}{c|}{Variação Percentual do $\delta_{\overline{N u}_{L_{p}}}$, conforme 
   variações nas incertezas:}                                                      
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Variação Percentual do $\delta_{R a_{L_{p}}}$, 
   conforme variações nas incertezas:}                                   
\\ 
\cline{2-8} 
& $\delta _{C_{t}}$ 
& $\delta _{m_{P}}$ 
& $\delta _{L_{P}}$ 
& $\delta _{\epsilon}$ 
& $\delta _{\overline{T}_{\text {inicial}}} = 
  \delta _{\overline{T}_{\text {final}}} = 
  \delta _{\overline{T}_{\infty}}$ 
& $\delta _{L_{P}}$ 
& $\delta _{\overline{T}_{\text {inicial}}} = 
  \delta _{\overline{T}_{\text {final}}} = 
  \delta _{\overline{T}_{\infty}}$ 
\\ \hline
-90\% & -0,1058\% & -0,0797\% & -0,0029\% & -88,0945\%   & -0,0204\% & -0,0879\% & -89,1567\%                                      
\\ \hline
-75\% & -0,1002\% & -0,0755\% & -0,0028\% & -74,2216\%   & -0,0193\% & -0,0833\% & -74,6693\%                                      
\\ \hline
-50\% & -0,0801\% & -0,0604\% & -0,0022\% & -49,6848\%   & -0,0154\% & -0,0666\% & -49,8670\%                                      
\\ \hline
-25\% & -0,0467\% & -0,0352\% & -0,0013\% & -24,8771\%   & -0,0090\% & -0,0388\% & -24,9482\%                                      
\\ \hline
+25\% & 0,0601\%  & 0,0453\%  & 0,0017\%  &  24,9051\%   & 0,0116\%  & +0,0499\% & +24,9600\%                                      
\\ \hline
+50\% & 0,1334\%  & 0,1006\%  & 0,0037\%  & 49,8242\%    & 0,0257\%  & +0,1109\% & +49,9260\%                                      
\\ \hline
+75\% & 0,2200\%  & 0,1659\%  & 0,0061\%  & 74,7514\%    & 0,0424\%  & +0,1829\% & +74,8953\%                                      
\\ \hline
+90\% & 0,2784\%  & 0,2099\%  & 0,0077\%  & 89,7102\%    & 0,0537\%  & +0,2314\% & +89,8780\%                                      
\\ \hline
+100\%& 0,3199\%  & 0,2412\%  & 0,0088\%  & 99,6835\%    & 0,0617\%  & +0,2660\% & +99,8668\%                                      
\\ \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\label{tab:sensib} 
\legend{Fonte: Próprio Autor.} 
\end{table} 
%\FloatBarrier % ??
\end{document}
```

Comment: you should show a complete example. \legend for example is not a standard command.

Comment: you have posted a fragment of code twice (once as code and once as a quote??) but it's just a fragment we can not run.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle drag the sidebar to view the entire code.

Comment: no the code should start `\documentclass`, define the commands that are used and end `\end{document}` the fragment you posted does none of those things so we can not debug uour issue. Was the second posi=ting as a quote a mistake? I am not sure what we can do with that at all?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of (a) reformatting your code and (b) makeing it minimally compilable. If you believe I've misunderstood something, please speak up.

Comment: @Mico, I appreciate your help. That's exactly it. I need help with formatting the table.

Comment: @Sílvio - All I  did was to make the code compilable. The table still needs *major* help in terms of decent formatting.

Comment: @Sílvio - It would really help if you stated which document class you employ, which font family and which main font size you've chosen, and how wide the text block is.

Comment: \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}%% Codificações de entrada: unix - latin1/utf8; windows - ansinew; Mac - applemax; DOS-OS/2 - cp850
\ifpdf%% Compilação com pdflatex
  \RequirePackage{cmap}%% Busca e cópia em arquivos PDF
  \RequirePackage{ae}%% Fontes virtuais para codificação de fontes T1
  \RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphics}%% Padrão gráfico de figuras

Comment: \RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}%% Aperfeiçoamentos do padrão gráfico de figuras
\else%% Compilação com latex
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}%% Codificação de fontes T1
  \RequirePackage{epic, eepic}%% Aperfeiçoamentos e extensões do ambiente figure
  \RequirePackage[dvips]{epsfig}%% Emulação de figuras (e)ps
  \RequirePackage[dvips]{graphics}%% Padrão gráfico de figuras
  \RequirePackage[dvips]{graphicx}%% Aperfeiçoamentos do padrão gráfico de figuras
\fi
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}%% Fontes "Computer Modern" em tamanhos arbitrários
\RequirePackage{hyphenat}%% Hifenização de palavras

Comment: @Sílvio - Please place LaTeX code in the body of your posting, *not* in a comment. Also, you still haven't indicated which document class you employ or

Answer (score 1):

The table has way too much wording. Only wrapping expressions or simply reducing number of words will help.

The solution below is only a recommendation. I guess I have wrongly divided words, so you will have to work it out yourself. I also added `booktabs` and `siunitx` for a better presentation.

EDIT. I missed two details in the first approach. The first is a note about all numbers, which represent percentage. The other is an author note.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}    % for \makecell and \cellalign
\usepackage{booktabs}    % for improved rules
\usepackage{siunitx}     % for number formatting in tables

% \providecommand\legend[1]{#1} % ??


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
    \centering
    \small
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\cellalign}{t}
    \caption{Análise de Sensibilidade dos parâmetros $\overline{N u}_{L_{p}}$ 
      e $R a_{L_{P}}$, em função das respectivas incertezas de medição 
      de influência.}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
            @{}
            @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
            S[table-format=-3]
            *3{S[table-format=-1.4]}
            S[table-format=-2.4]
            *2{S[table-format=-1.4]}
            S[table-format=-2.4]
            @{}
        }
        \addlinespace\toprule
        {\multirow[t]{2}*{\makecell{
                    Variação\\
                    Percentual\\
                    da\\
                    Incerteza\\
                    de\\
                    Medição}}}
            & \multicolumn{5}{c}{%
                \makecell{%
                    Variação Percentual do \smash{\(\delta_{\overline{N u}_{L_{p}}}\)}\\
                    conforme variações nas incertezas:}}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{%
                \makecell{%
                    Variação Percentual\\do \smash{\(\delta_{R a_{L_{p}}}\)} conforme\\
                    variações nas incertezas:}} \\ 
        \cmidrule{2-6}\cmidrule{7-8}
        & {\(\delta _{C_{t}}\)}
            & {\(\delta _{m_{P}}\)}
            & {\(\delta _{L_{P}}\)}
            & {\(\delta _{\epsilon}\)} 
            & {\makecell[t]{%
                \(\delta _{\overline{T}_{\text {inicial}}}\)\\
                \(\delta _{\overline{T}_{\text {final}}}\)\\
                \(\delta _{\overline{T}_{\infty}}\)}}
            & {$\delta _{L_{P}}$}
            & {\makecell[t]{%
                \(\delta _{\overline{T}_{\text {inicial}}}\)\\
                \(\delta _{\overline{T}_{\text {final}}}\)\\
                \(\delta _{\overline{T}_{\infty}}\)}} \\
        \addlinespace\midrule
        -90 & -0,1058 & -0,0797 & -0,0029 & -88,0945   & -0,0204 & -0,0879 & -89,1567 \\
        -75 & -0,1002 & -0,0755 & -0,0028 & -74,2216   & -0,0193 & -0,0833 & -74,6693 \\
        -50 & -0,0801 & -0,0604 & -0,0022 & -49,6848   & -0,0154 & -0,0666 & -49,8670 \\
        -25 & -0,0467 & -0,0352 & -0,0013 & -24,8771   & -0,0090 & -0,0388 & -24,9482 \\
        +25 & 0,0601  & 0,0453  & 0,0017  &  24,9051   & 0,0116  & +0,0499 & +24,9600 \\
        +50 & 0,1334  & 0,1006  & 0,0037  & 49,8242    & 0,0257  & +0,1109 & +49,9260 \\
        +75 & 0,2200  & 0,1659  & 0,0061  & 74,7514    & 0,0424  & +0,1829 & +74,8953 \\
        +90 & 0,2784  & 0,2099  & 0,0077  & 89,7102    & 0,0537  & +0,2314 & +89,8780 \\
        +100& 0,3199  & 0,2412  & 0,0088  & 99,6835    & 0,0617  & +0,2660 & +99,8668 \\
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{8}{c}{Note: a note that all quantities are in (\%)} \\
        \multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{Fonte: Próprio Autor.}
    \end{tabular*} 
    \label{tab:sensib}%\legend{Fonte: Próprio Autor.} 
\end{table}
%\FloatBarrier % ??
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is long text in the headers stretch the columns very wide. I've replaced the header text of the last two columns with

```
\multicolumn{2}{c}{
    \parbox{16em}{
        \centering\smallskip
        Variação Percentual do $\delta_{R a_{L_{p}}}$,
        conforme variações nas incertezas:
        \smallskip
    }
}
```

which restricts the text to 16em (roughly 20 capital letters wide).

[image: Long table columns better]

(Note it's missing the legend. I don't know what you packages you're using for that.)

Additionally, I've made the columns equally wide (except for the long `$delta ... = delta ... = delta ...$` ones). This is done by adding before your `\begin{document}` the code

```
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{6em}}
```

Now instead of the `c` column alignment, we can also use `P`. This is also a centered column, but precisely `6em` wide. I replace your `{c|c|...|c}` by `{c|P|P|P|P|c|P|c}`. This gives the result shown.

The full code behind this image (also on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/8StLqGUm):

```
% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598089/columns-horizontal-alignment/598091#598091
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
 
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{6em}}
 
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \caption{Análise de Sensibilidade dos parâmetros $\overline{N u}_{L_{p}}$ e $R a_{L_{P}}$, em função das respectivas incertezas de medição de influência.}
        %
        \begin{tabular}{c*{4}{|P}|c*{1}{|P}|c}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Variação Percentual da\\ Incerteza de Medição\end{tabular}} & 
            \multicolumn{5}{c|}{
                Variação Percentual do $\delta_{\overline{N u}_{L_{p}}}$, conforme variações nas incertezas:
            }
&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{
    \parbox{16em}{
        \centering\smallskip
        Variação Percentual do $\delta_{R a_{L_{p}}}$,
        conforme variações nas incertezas:
        \smallskip
    }
}
\\ \cline{2-8} 
                                                                                                               & $\delta _{C_{t}}$ & $\delta _{m_{P}}$ & $\delta _{L_{P}}$ & $\delta _{\epsilon}$ & $\delta _{\overline{T}_{\text {inicial}}} = \delta _{\overline{T}_{\text {final}}} = \delta _{\overline{T}_{\infty}}$ & $\delta _{L_{P}}$ & $\delta _{\overline{T}_{\text {inicial}}} = \delta _{\overline{T}_{\text {final}}} = \delta _{\overline{T}_{\infty}}$ \\ \hline
        -90\%                                                                                                  & -0,1058\%         & -0,0797\%         & -0,0029\%         & -88,0945\%           & -0,0204\%                                                                                                             & -0,0879\%         & -89,1567\%                                                                                                            \\ \hline
        -75\%                                                                                                  & -0,1002\%         & -0,0755\%         & -0,0028\%         & -74,2216\%           & -0,0193\%                                                                                                             & -0,0833\%         & -74,6693\%                                                                                                            \\ \hline
        -50\%                                                                                                  & -0,0801\%         & -0,0604\%         & -0,0022\%         & -49,6848\%           & -0,0154\%                                                                                                             & -0,0666\%         & -49,8670\%                                                                                                            \\ \hline
        -25\%                                                                                                  & -0,0467\%         & -0,0352\%         & -0,0013\%         & -24,8771\%           & -0,0090\%                                                                                                             & -0,0388\%         & -24,9482\%                                                                                                            \\ \hline
        +25\%                                                                                                  & 0,0601\%          & 0,0453\%          & 0,0017\%          & 24,9051\%            & 0,0116\%                                                                                                              & +0,0499\%         & +24,9600\%                                                                                                            \\ \hline
        +50\%                                                                                                  & 0,1334\%          & 0,1006\%          & 0,0037\%          & 49,8242\%            & 0,0257\%                                                                                                              & +0,1109\%         & +49,9260\%                                                                                                            \\ \hline
        +75\%                                                                                                  & 0,2200\%          & 0,1659\%          & 0,0061\%          & 74,7514\%            & 0,0424\%                                                                                                              & +0,1829\%         & +74,8953\%                                                                                                            \\ \hline
        +90\%                                                                                                  & 0,2784\%          & 0,2099\%          & 0,0077\%          & 89,7102\%            & 0,0537\%                                                                                                              & +0,2314\%         & +89,8780\%                                                                                                            \\ \hline
        +100\%                                                                                                 & 0,3199\%          & 0,2412\%          & 0,0088\%          & 99,6835\%            & 0,0617\%                                                                                                              & +0,2660\%         & +99,8668\%                                                                                                            \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tab:sensib}
        %\legend{Fonte: Próprio Autor.}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: unless the pastebin will be archived forever, better to add it inline here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle de pastebin says 'ever' for the expire time, and I've outlined all my modifications here, but I will add the full code here too, just to be sure